# Enabled multi-org connector but can see existing sync'ed entities in child BU's

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, multi-org

We have recently upgraded our MC account to multi org, I have connected the child business unit to the same ORG as our parent BU. We have one org, two BU's, both need to be connected independently to the ORG to allow filtering of which records we need.

Navigating to the Contact Builder > Data Sources > Synchronised shows 0 entities and attributes synced (which is what we expect) however if I click on the Sync'ed Data Source the page shows 10 synchronised objects which is basically the same sync'ed objects in our parent BU.

How can I independently sync which objects and fields are available in my child BU? It was my understanding this is what the multi-org connector would enable.

Comment: Have you used separate API users for the connections, or did you use the same API users in both BUs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to do that, you need separate API users in Salesforce CRM and one API user in Marketing Cloud that has access to both of the BUs that you want to connect.

Here’s how to set this up:

1. In first BU, go to Setup > Apps > Salesforce Integration and connect the accounts using Salesforce API user 1
2. In first BU, go to users and click on the SFMC API user and click on Salesforce.com Status to integrate it. Use Salesforce API user 1 for the mapping and save changes.
3. In second BU, go to Setup > Apps > Salesforce Integration and connect the accounts using Salesforce API user 2
4. In second BU, go to users and click on the SFMC API user and click on Salesforce.com Status to integrate it. Use Salesforce API user 2 for the mapping and save changes.
5. In Salesforce, go to the Marketing Cloud tab and connect from Salesforce to Marketing Cloud using the SFMC API user credentials.

Now you should be all set and able to synch different data sets from Salesforce to Marketing Cloud.